# Python "Invalid Argument" error while reading large txt file

Tags: python, nlp, bigdata

I am trying to preprocess a large `.txt` file, that is around 12GB.
The following code gives an

> Invalid Argument

error. I think it happens because the data is too large.
Is there any way to read a document this big?
Do I need this big data to train the words to generate word vectors?
Or is there some other error?

```
with open('data/text8') as f:
    text = f.read()
```

Comment: `f.read()` loads the ENTIRE file into memory. Unless you have crazy amounts of RAM, that's not going to work. If you can, try iterating over the file.

Comment: Does the error come during execution or compilation?  What line produces the problem?

Comment: @Tomothy32 12gigs isn't exactly a crazy amount of RAM. Anyway, post of the full error message including the stack trace.  The code you've posted wouldn't throw that error.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I may be wrong, but I would say that 12GB is pretty huge. The majority of consumer PCs these days have 8 or 16GB, and on my 16GB machine, if you have some other memory-heavy programs open, 12GB definitely won't fit.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what sort of text processing you are intending, maybe reading one line at a time should suffice:

```
f = open("data/text8", "r")
for line in f:
    # process the string 'line' as desired (it's a single line of the document you opened)

f.close()
```